# Interface with a list of Interfaces

Tags: c#, generics, interface

Maybe I'm dumb but ...

I have:

```
public interface IRequest
{
    IList<IRequestDetail> Details { get; set; }

    // stuff
}

public interface IRequestDetail
{
    // stuff
}
```

I then have:

```
public class MyRequest : IRequest
{
    IList<MyRequestDetail> Details {get; set; }

    // stuff
}

public class MyRequestDetail : IRequestDetail
{
    // stuff
}
```

It doesn't work.

C# gets pissed at me because MyRequest does not implement the interface due to not having an IList of IRequestDetail.

Now if I change it so the Details is IList of IRequestDetail I then have to cast it to MyRequestDetail everywhere in the code I use a non-interface member (I have several requests that share common stuff, but then specialize).

I kind of understand why its wrong, but not fully!

Comment: I think with the casting, you are removing the precepts of what an Interface does.

Comment: Yah... when writing "I have several requests that share common stuff, but then specialize" I kinda realized that maybe I got interface crazy and overlooked that this is better to just inherit?  I'm not sure if it would have the same issue or not.

Comment: @huey, you'd have the same issue, but less code to write. :) I try to do YAGNI (You Aren't Going To Need It), but interfaces are my one vice. I make far too many of them so that I can use mock frameworks in unit tests

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think, based on the question that the problem is that you want to treat Details as a generic list and enforce that it implements IRequestDetail.  You also want it to be more specifically typed for the implementing classes.  In this case, you need to make IRequest generic.

Try this:

```
public interface IRequest<T> where T : IRequestDetail
{
    IList<T> Details { get; set; }

    // stuff
}

public class MyRequest : IRequest<MyRequestDetail>
{
    public IList<MyRequestDetail> Details {get; set; }

    // stuff
}
```

This should work for you.

**EDIT 2017-03-17**

In reply to @Robert's comment, see the expanded code below:

```
public interface IRequestDetail
{

}

public class MyRequestDetail : IRequestDetail
{

}

public interface IRequest<T> where T : IRequestDetail
{
    IList<T> Details { get; set; }

    // stuff
}

public class MyRequest<T> : IRequest<T>
    where T : IRequestDetail
{
    public IList<T> Details { get; set; }

    // stuff
}

public class Consumer
{
    public void MyFunction<T>(IRequest<T> request)
        where T : IRequestDetail
    {

    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var test = new MyRequest<MyRequestDetail>();
        MyFunction(test);
    }
}
```

Comment: I used your pattern to solve a similar problem. Now let's assume I have function which accepts an `IRequest` object and doesn't care about it's actual implementation. I tried to implement that function like this: `MyFunction(IRequest<IRequestDetail> request)`. The problem is that it doesn't accept an object of type `MyRequest`. So how would I pass an actual implementation (like `MyRequest`) to a function that only knows about the interfaces?

Comment: @RobertHegner see the edit to the post for a more detailed example which (hopefully) answers your question. Note the "Consumer" class. The MyFunction method has a generic constraint that allows the passing of a class MyRequest<MyRequestDetail>.

Answer (score 2):

Exact.
Michael has the solution.
the problem is a little trickier.

its that there is no explicit conversion from

```
IList<MyRequestDetail>
```

to

```
IList<IRequestDetail>
```

because that would imply that you can add other objects, that are based on different classes (e.g. MyRequestDetail2), that are not "MyRequestDetail" to the second object.
and that would be illegal for the first.

Comment: Okay, I felt like it made sense why it didn't work... but couldn't explain exactly why.  That explains exactly why it shouldn't work.

Comment: You do lose the ability to cast the list due to lack of covariance (pre-4.0, see @Reed Copsey's answer: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/807720/interface-with-a-list-of-interfaces/807791#807791). It's also true that in my answer, MyRequest can't be cast to IRequest<IRequestDetail> while it can be cast to IRequest<MyRequestDetail>. It becomes a problem when the generic type is not available to referencing libraries/executables.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to covariance and contravariance in C#.  There is a very detailed, very clear explaination of the issues (split into many parts) on [Eric Lippert's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ericlippert/archive/tags/Covariance+and+Contravariance/default.aspx).